# What is the diffrence between int (*arr)[20] , int arr[][7]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Thats what I think I understood by now:

1. `int arr[][5]` - means that arr is a pointer to array of 5 numbers.
   I have failed to implement the following:

   ```
   int arr2[5];
   int arr[][5]=&arr2;
   ERROR:  initializer fails to determine size of ‘arr’.
   ```

Thats what I can't understand:

1. I have no idea what does `()` in `(*arr)[20]` means and what arr represents.

Thanks!

Comment: `int arr[][5]=&arr2;` are you actually trying to assign?

Comment: Surely I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Use http://www.cdecl.org/ to translate a C declaration into English.

Comment: You can't assign to an array. You can only initialize its contents, `int arr[][5] = {...};`

Comment: Sory, my mistake. I updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have no idea what does () in (*arr)[20] means and what arr represents.

`()` has higher precedence that `[]` which itself has higher precedence than `*`. Therefor `()` makes `arr` a pointer to array, otherwise it becomes array of pointers.

```
int (*arr)[20];   // pointer to array of 20 int
int *arr[20];     // array of 20 pointers to int
```

---

```
int arr[][5]=&arr2;
```

That assignment is invalid. Two reasons:

- Assign an array to an address is not possible. When you declare an array in the stack, it is allocated a fixed location in the memory. The name of the array therefore can be thought of a `const` pointer - because it's const it cannot be reassigned to point any other address.
- Also, if you omit the size of an array at the time of definition, you must provide initialisation for the array - otherwise how can the compiler know the size of the array?

---

From @BLUEPIXY - what you want is (must fix the definition of `arr` to pointer first):

```
int arr2[5];
int (*arr)[5]=&arr2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you also explain why I got the errors in the first part of the question?

Comment: @StavAlfi the first part of the question is clearly invalid - see answer

Comment: `Assign an array to an address is not possible` , I assigned the address of arr2 to arr1 which is a pointer to array of size 5. Cant understand the problem..

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Then what does arr represents?

Comment: @StavAlfi 2D-Array of `int`.

Comment: @StavAlfi You want `int (*arr)[5]=&arr2;`, not `int arr[][5]=&arr2;`

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY for the extra help!